# $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the $K$-algebra generated by $A$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let K be an algebraically closed field and let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over $K$ for some $n$. Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the $K$-algebra generated by $A$ in $M_{n\times n}(K)$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements.

---

Can anyone give a hint how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: The $\;K\,-$ algebra...within the algebra $\;M_n(K)\;$ of **all** $\;n\times n\;$ matrices, or *where* ?

Comment: it will be in $M_n(K)$. Thanks

Comment: Well, a rather foggy hint could be that the *only* nilpotent *diagonal* matrix is the zero matrix, and from here sufficiency could probably be deduces.

Comment: One side is trivial, isn't it? : $A$ is diagonalizable $\rightarrow$  any element in the algebra is diagonalizable $\rightarrow$ in particular, the nilpotent element is  diagonalizable $\rightarrow$  the nilpotent element is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any matrix $A \in M_n(K)$ can be written as $A = A_S + A_N$ where $A_S$ is diagonalizable, $A_N$ is nilpotent, $[A_S, A_N] = 0$ and both $A_S,A_N$ are polynomials in $A$ (this is called the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition).

If $A$ is diagonalizable and $g \in K[X]$ then $g(A)$ is also diagonalizable and so if $g(A)^r = 0$ then $g(A)$ is both nilpotent and diagonalizable which implies that $g(A) = 0$ so the algebra $\left< A \right> = \left \{ g(A) \, | \, g \in K[X] \right \}$ generated by $A$ inside $M_{n}(K)$ has no non-zero nilpotent elements.

On the other hand, if $\left< A \right>$ has no non-zero nilpotent elements, then writing $A_N = g(A)$ we have $g(A)^n = 0$ and so $A_N = g(A) = 0$ which shows that $A$ is diagonalizable.